# Facebook App Style UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, fullscreen

I have bunch of images inside a UIScrollView and have a tap event setup on each image. When I try to make the image full screen it actually is cut off by the scroll view. I am trying to implement a Facebook style UIImageView where the image zoom in and takes over the full screen on tap.

Does anyone have suggestion on how to approach this cause the way I am doing the image is cropped to the size of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually you would disable clipping, but the scrollview relies on clipping to do its job so that won't work.

My suggestion would be to push a copy of the image above the scrollview, and animate that to full screen. You should be able to get the rect using `convertRect:toView:` and it would be pretty straightforward from there.

btw, Is there a reason not to use a tableView for this?

Comment: Images are horizontally laid out

Answer (score 0):

When tapped hide the image and add the image at the proper place in the scrollview superview and over the scrollview. Then animate it to take the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook App style UIImageView is nicely implemented in below given source code, you can take a clue from this
https://github.com/michaelhenry/MHFacebookImageViewer